# ionic display array result in template

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to display the results from an array into the html template. I need to display the tasks objects. Currently I can successfully console log the result but when I try to display it I get a blank ion-list. I am retrieving the array from Ionic storage.

```
[
  {
    "projects": {
      "projectname": "test",
      "dateadded": "09 April 2018, 6:29AM",
      "location": "us",
      "tasks": {
        "0": {
          "taskname": "test",
          "taskdescription": "test",
          "taskdealer": "test",
          "tasksupplier": "Technical",
          "taskdeadline": "2018-04-08"
        },
        "1": {
          "taskname": "test",
          "taskdescription": "test",
          "taskdealer": "test",
          "tasksupplier": "Technical",
          "taskdeadline": "2018-04-08"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

My attempt

```
this.storage.get('projectsStore').then(data => {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      console.log(data[i].projects.tasks);
      this.tasks = [data[i].projects.tasks];
    }
})

<ion-list>
  <button ion-item no-padding *ngFor="let item of tasks">
    <h2>{{item.taskname}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.taskdeadline}}</p>
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: can you show the log of this.tasks

Comment: `{  
   "0":{  
      "taskname":"test",
      "taskdescription":"test",
      "taskdealer":"test",
      "tasksupplier":"Technical",
      "taskdeadline":"2018-04-08"
   },
   "1":{  
      "taskname":"test",
      "taskdescription":"test",
      "taskdealer":"test",
      "tasksupplier":"Technical",
      "taskdeadline":"2018-04-08"
   }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot repeat Object. Convert it to array like following. It should work like that:

```
this.storage.get('projectsStore').then(data => {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      console.log(data[i].projects.tasks);
      this.tasks = Object.values(data[i].projects.tasks);
    }
})
```

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/feLnekjb/1/ . Click to see your list getting repeated.

Comment: thanks but I get "[ts] Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'."

Comment: fixed the above error, but still get an empty display. If I display this `<h2>{{item}}</h2>` then I get [object, object],[object, object]. If I display this `<h2>{{item.taskname}}</h2>`, I get nothing

Comment: can you log your this.tasks after the above step and show here

Comment: `[  
   {  
      "0":{  
         "taskname":"test",
         "taskdescription":"test",
         "taskdealer":"test",
         "tasksupplier":"Technical",
         "taskdeadline":"2018-04-08"
      },
      "1":{  
         "taskname":"test",
         "taskdescription":"test",
         "taskdealer":"test",
         "tasksupplier":"Technical",
         "taskdeadline":"2018-04-08"
      }
   }
]`